# .net preview 7 - c++ static virtual methods of interfaces are not supported and will be unavailable

Tags: .net-core, c++-cli

I'm trying to use:

Visual Studio = Version 17.3.0 Preview 1.1

And Microsoft.NET SDK 7.0.100-preview.4.22252.9 (x64)

I've been able to compile some csproj projects but for my vcxproj I am getting:
6>C:\Development\Source\ApmUpdateDotNet7\framework\oqkern\shared\ManagedDateTime.cpp(31,4): error C2220: the following warning is treated as an error
6>C:\Development\Source\ApmUpdateDotNet7\framework\oqkern\shared\ManagedDateTime.cpp(31,4): warning C4679: 'Parse': could not import member
6>C:\Development\Source\ApmUpdateDotNet7\framework\oqkern\shared\ManagedDateTime.cpp(31,4): message : static virtual methods of interfaces are not supported and will be unavailable
6>C:\Development\Source\ApmUpdateDotNet7\framework\oqkern\shared\ManagedDateTime.cpp(31,4): message : This diagnostic occurred while importing type 'System::IParsable' from assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.

This seems like it might be related:

https://github.com/dotnet/docs/issues/28542

Comment: Appreciate linking the github issue as I'm hitting the same.

Answer (score 0):

I got help at the github issue linked above

> This is expected. C++/CLI changed what was a hard error into a
> warning. You likely have /warnaserror or similar enabled (as per the
> following warning is treated as an error) and so you'll need to
> disable C4679.

[image]